# Where should we store PIN when implementing PIN login within a mobile application?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile

I'm interested to get peoples opinions on this one.

Where do people stand on implementation of PIN logins within a mobile application?

More specifically where should the PIN be stored?

Say we have a standard API endpoint to authenticate against which will return us an auth token. The user enters their username and password, we send this to the auth endpoint and return the auth token if valid.

Now the user can also set a PIN to use if they have logged in and authenticated previously. In the past when implementing this I have always stored the users PIN encrypted in secure storage on the device. If the user enters their PIN we validate this input against the one saved in storage. If the PINs match we then grab the saved refresh token from the previous auth response and use this to get a new token then we are authenticated with the API and can log the user in and begin retrieving data again.

My question is if people think this is robust enough or whether we should also be storing the PIN in a cloud database and validating through the API instead of locally on the device.

Comment: The approach you described above is fairly standard. And it is fine. I'm not sure about the benefit you would get from moving PIN off-device (cloud DB). It would be like a second password. You could also add biometric validation to your PIN (another fairly common practice).

Comment: Yes I thought so. Thanks for your response. I was interested to hear peoples opinions.